# Passing data from page to page firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, get, snapshot

I am trying to pass firebase snapshot data from first page to second page in flutter using GET. **I'm able to pass data from one screen to another in debug mode but not in release mode.**

I have used a streambuilder on the page and a Future on second . Please where am i going wrong ?

here is code..

first page:

```
 Container(
          child: Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Songs')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }

                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.white24,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.purple, width: 2)),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(document['title'],
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  document['artist'],
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Get.to(() => DetailsPage(
                                        piss: document,
                                        post: document.id,
                                      ));
                                },
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                leading: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
                                trailing: document['isNew'] == true
                                    ? Image.asset(
                                        'assets/new.gif',
                                      )
                                    : null),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
        _banner == null
            ? Container()
            : Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                height: 52,
                child: AdWidget(
                  ad: _banner!,
                ),
              ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

second page

```
 FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: widget.piss['tileHeaders'].length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _index = index;
                              counter = counter + 1;

                              print('COUNTER: $counter');
                              if (counter == 3) {
                                _showRewardedAd();
                                _controller.play();
                                print("Counter is $counter");
                                counter = 0;
                                _createRewardedAd();
                              }
                            });
                            index > 0
                                ? playIt(index)
                                : _controller
                                    .load(widget.piss['videos'][index]);
                          },
                          child: Card(
                              elevation: 5,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Center(
                                              child: Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            child: Expanded(
                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                  "assets/logo.png"),
                                              flex: 2,
```

//                                      flex: 2,),
),
)),
Expanded(
child: Container(
alignment:
Alignment.topLeft,
child: Column(
children: [
Expanded(
flex: 5,
child: ListTile(
title: Text(
widget.piss[
'tileHeaders']
[index],
style: TextStyle(
fontSize:
26)),
),
),
Expanded(
flex: 5,
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment:
MainAxisAlignment
.end,
children: [
Container(
child: widget
.piss[
'videos']
[
index]
.toString()
.contains(
'PL')
? Center(
child:
Container(child: playlist()),
)
: Center(
child:
Container(
child:
notPlaylist(),
),
),
),
],
))
],
)),
)
],
))
],
)),
);
}),
);
}
})

Please help

Comment: Please share the code of both screens here. Because no future builder is required onto other screen, if same data is being used onto next one.

Comment: Ok will do , il share it when i get home from work . Thankyou

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have now pasted the code up at the top. Anyone's help would be much appreciated